# bokeh: adding details to a high level chart

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

What is the simplest way to combine high level charts (like Bar) with something else (like a line)?

```
b = Bar(df)
b.line(df.mean())
```

This won't work because `b` is not a figure.

1. How can I get the figure handle from `b`? (and/or)
2. How can I create the line and bar separately and then combine?

(I'm trying to avoid making the bar manually using the lower level quad or rect.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
b.add_glyph(data_source, line)
```

where:

```
data_source = bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource(dict(x=df.index, y=df.your_column))
line = bokeh.models.glyphs.Line(x='x', y='y', line_color='blue')
```